# Error when using Goth get token google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, elixir, token, google-cloud-storage

I'm using {:ok, goth} = Goth.Token.for_scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control")
But i seen a bug. Please help me

`** (exit) an exception was raised:
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function :crypto.mpint/1 is undefined or private
(crypto) :crypto.mpint(19687873431742193920055970243130294467124206658682087298983794038798216955530975915146333586732314900700035611611045789143545904247799428447896803420118324471667046274052296120024954651561469080093219328190691149886440049200669636272584661976356321702914680136369124759272732574776698998044554776915282967732669956832401458331945711479325049514685797410840542208523089896590986235120222095570675226125560522026179882816977851505433864383972624362893774956738669017687990725035030542706539434148824251987312659383648295704127681204473207295376320651645980971185202320992998884262991006767805018245431366563316696488933)`

Comment: Do you have the package erlang-crypto installed?

Answer (score 1):

Please check that you are using Goth 0.6.0 or later version, so that json_web_token will be updated to its newest version that does not rely on `mpint/1`.

More detailed explanation:

`:crypto.mpint/1` was removed in the latest version of Erlang/OTP 20 since it was deprecated few versions ago.

Goth has a dependency called json_web_token which used to use `mpint/1` up until the middle of 2017. Since then version 0.2.10 was released as an emergency fix for the removal of `mpint/1` in the crypto package and you can see that Goth had this dependency updated in the summer also - https://github.com/peburrows/goth/commit/b983dc15447ee6b59a0f170f5a47da9e298549ff .